# Connecting to SSAS OLAP using Java

Tags: java, ssas, olap

We are currently working on creating a connection to Microsoft SSAS OLAP server using Java. The approaches mentioned on google include using IIS server with msmdpump.dll which we are trying to avoid. We want to bypass IIS and just connect through Tomcat.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Never used it myself, but I've heard this be recommended http://www.olap4j.org/

Comment: Thanks but even OLAP4J uses msmdpump :(

Comment: @user2065154 I take it you've read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518527/best-way-to-access-ms-analysis-services-cube-from-java ?